# django user field (populated with django.contrib.auth) in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeladmin

I dont know why but the Django Admin App does not find the user field in the model. Can you help with that?

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    in_use = models.BooleanField()
```

admin.py:

```
from project.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'user', 'in_use']
```

Error message:

ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/

'ObjectAdmin.fieldsets[3][1]['fields']' refers to field 'user' that is missing from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because `user` is marked as `editable=False`. Try using [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and add user to that `ModelAdmin` option.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the django.contrib.auth app activated in your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings and you have to set the name of your profile model in AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE,

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "object"
```

Also, you should consider changing the name of your model, Python wont like you naming your model "object"